# How to set layout in module zend zf1

Tags: zend-framework

My dir i project is:

```
var
 -www
   -appwar
     -s1
       -application
         -controllers
         -models
         -modules
           -quests
            -controllers
            -models
            -views
              -scripts
                main.phtml
         -views
          -scripts
            layout.phtml
```

In main application i use layout.phtml but when i add module and in controller i code

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('main');
```

everything is ok but i would like use layout from main project and when i change for

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout'); or 
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('/application/views/scripts/layout');
```

doesn't work :( Do U know how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before setLayout():

```
// If APPLICATION_PATH == '/var/www/appwar/s1/application'
$this->_helper->layout->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts');
```

Comment: I did $this->_helper->layout->setLayoutPath('var/www/appwar/s1/application/views/scripts/'); 
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('main'); and still nothing. Maybe i have wrong with main bootsrap.